# can we set order to a table by wildcard in visual foxpro?

Tags: sorting, wildcard, visual-foxpro

I am having a table in which I have to get the records having the word which I entered followed by the remaining records. (Sorting), I tried with "set filter to"  but it is only showing the filtered records but I want all the records starting with the word containing ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the original table ordered in this way, create an index tag that sorts the ones with the word first, something like:

```
INDEX ON IIF('word'$field, 1, 2) TAG WordFirst
```

If a copy of the data will do, use a query something like:

```
SELECT IIF('word'$field, 1, 2) AS WordFirst, *  ;
  FROM YourTable ;
  ORDER BY 1 ;
  INTO CURSOR csrWordFirst
```

What's nice about the second version is that you can add other fields to the sort order, so that you can sort within the records with and the records without the word.